# LocalStorage storing multiple div hides

Tags: javascript, html, hide, local-storage

I am using a simple code to hide multiple divs if the link to hide them is clicked. 
On one of them I have local storage set-up to remember of the div is hidden or not.
The thing is this. How can I write a code to make local storage remember the hidden state of multiple divs WITHOUT having to put localstorage.setItem for each individual div. Is it possible to store an array with the div ids and their display set to true or false to decide if the page should show them or not?

***************EDITED*************************

```
function ShowHide(id) {
if(document.getElementById(id).style.display = '') {
document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
}
else if (document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none') {
document.getElementById(id).style.display = ''; 
}
```

Comment: You'd probably want to use an object, not an array

Comment: Do you have an example code?

Answer (score 1):

Like you said, you already have an array storing all your state. You can serialize this using [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and put the result into `localStorage`.

```
 // your array
 var divstate = [ ... ];

 // store it
 localStorage.setItem( 'divstate', JSON.stringify( divstate ) );
```

If you want to retrieve the array again, use [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

```
 // restore
 var divstate = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem( 'divstate' );
```

**EDIT**

To store the actual ids of all divs, you probably will use something like this

```
var divstate = {
  'divid1': true,
  'divid2': false,
  ...
};
```

This can easily be used with the above pattern.

**2nd EDIT**

For the above code I would suggest loading the state variable once at page load using the above statement.

Then transform the function like this:

```
function ShowHide(id) {
  var el = document.getElementById(id);

  if ( divstate[id] === true ) {
    divstate[id] = false;
    el.style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    divstate[id] = true;
    el.style.display = '';
  }

  localStorage.setItem( 'divstate', JSON.stringify( divstate ) );
}
```

That way the `divstate` is updated and stored with each function call.

Note, that I would not recommend this, if the number of divs is too high, but for smaller amounts this should be sufficient.

Comment: See my edit to my question to see a rough draft of the code I am using to hide my divs. How can I implement local storage into that along with your code?

Comment: Thanks :D I will try it out as soon as Im around my code again. I would upvote but I dont have the reputation :(